# Foto tirada da câmera Android erro API 21

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Ao fazer uma foto com a câmera do android minha app cria um preview dessa foto em uma Activity onde será enviado por e-mail, porém o código abaixo está funcionando perfeitamente para o android abaixo da versão 4.4.1 e acima dela no momento de capturar o caminho da imagem para gerar o preview ele encerra a app e acusa nullPointerException e o result=-1.
Alguém sabe me informar como faço para que também funcione nas versões acima do 4.4.1 android?

Preview onde serão inseridas as fotos.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/previewFoto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>
```

Código para a câmera:

```
private String caminhoFoto = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_send__email);
  camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intentCamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            caminhoFoto = getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg";
            Log.i("CAMINHO",caminhoFoto);
            File arquivoFoto = new File(caminhoFoto);
            intentCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(arquivoFoto));
            startActivityForResult(intentCamera, CODIGO_CAMERA);
        }
    });

  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == CODIGO_CAMERA){
            carregaImagem(caminhoFoto);
        } else if(requestCode == CODIGO_GALERIA){
            try{
                listaImagem(intent);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
 private void carregaImagem(String caminhoFoto) {

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(caminhoFoto);
    Bitmap bitmapReduzido = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 300,300, true);

    LinearLayout lista = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.previewFoto);

    ImageView foto = new ImageView(this);
    foto.setImageBitmap(bitmapReduzido);
    foto.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    lista.addView(foto);
}
```

Comment: Parece ser um problema de permissão.

Esse código funciona para mim.

 ´String caminho = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Android/data/" + getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/files/Pictures/";
                                                          File folder = new File(caminho);

                                                          if (!folder.exists()) {
                                                              folder.mkdir();
                                                          }´

Comment: o método getActivity() não é reconhecido, está pedindo para que eu crie o método ou importe o android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(). Qual opção devo seguir?